# iOS4 UISearchBar localization of cancel button

Tags: iphone

I have tested my app on 3.1.3 and when the device language is set to German it displays the `UISearchBar` cancel button localized into German. On iOS4 it displays as "Cancel". Is there anything specific I need to do in iOS4 to trigger the cancel button to display as a localized string?

Comment: Setting "Localization native development region" as German in the info.plist solved the issue.

Comment: Take care, it seems not working in the simulator. Make your tests on device.

Answer (score 4):

Change the Cancel button title:

```
for (UIView *subview in [searchBar subviews]) {
    if ([NSStringFromClass([subview class]) isEqualToString:@"UINavigationButton"]){
        // http://github.com/kennytm/iphone-private-frameworks/blob/master/UIKit/UINavigationButton.h
        [subview performSelector:@selector(setTitle:) withObject:@"newTitle"];
    }
}
```

You can also find the cancel button looking for an element with dimensions 48,30. Use `CGRect bounds = [subview bounds]; CGSize size = bounds.size;`

Comment: If you would like to keep from comparing class names as strings I am writing a more general method below (might be more robust after SDK updates?).  Great post, worth the up vote :)

for (UIView *subview in [searchBar subviews])
 {
  if ([[subview class] isSubclassOfClass:[UIButton class]])
   [subview performSelector:@selector(setTitle:) withObject:[[[[LocaleManager sharedLocaleManager] languageDictionary] valueForKey:@"General"] valueForKey:@"cancelButtonTitle"]];
 }